# Existe um equivalente ao @@ROWCOUNT do SQLSERVER no Postgres?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou migrando o Banco de algumas aplicações, de SQLServer para Postgres e diversos scripts utilizam @@rowcount. Existe um equivalente no Postgres ao @@rowcount?

Comment: Até onde sei, nao existe nenhum equivalente direto. Você provavelmente vai ter que criar sub-querys fazendo uso de COUNT(*) , GROUP BY e HAVING.

Comment: Isso no `SELECT` ou `UPDATE`?

Comment: Depende do que vc esteja tentando fazer.

Achei esses dois links (abaixo) que falam sobre GET DIAGNOSTICS. Nao sei como funciona. Vc teria que dar uma procurada.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200307250905.21817.dev%40archonet.com
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109074/rowcount-in-postgresql-9-3

Comment: @Sorack Update e Delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a instrução `GET DIAGNOSTICS` após a sua instrução principal para obter o número de linhas afetadas. Por exemplo:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  linhas INTEGER;
BEGIN
  UPDATE tabela
     SET valor = 'valor';
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE NOTICE'Nenhuma linha encontrada %';
  ELSIF FOUND THEN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS linhas := ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE'Linhas afetadas: %', linhas;
  END IF; 
END $$;
```

---

> [**39.5.5. Obtaining the Result Status**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/plpgsql-statements.html)
>
> There are several ways to determine the effect of a command. The first method is to use the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` command, which has the form:
>
> ```
> GET DIAGNOSTICS variable = item [ , ... ];
> ```
>
> This command allows retrieval of system status indicators. Each `item` is a key word identifying a state value to be assigned to the specified variable (which should be of the right data type to receive it). The currently available status items are `ROW_COUNT`, the number of rows processed by the last SQL command sent to the SQL engine, and `RESULT_OID`, the `OID` of the last row inserted by the most recent SQL command. Note that `RESULT_OID` is only useful after an `INSERT` command into a table containing `OIDs`.

Em tradução livre:

> [**39.5.5. Obtendo o Status do Resultado**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/plpgsql-statements.html)
>
> Existem várias maneiras de determinar o efeito de um comando. O primeiro método é usar o comando `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, que tem a forma:
>
> ```
> GET DIAGNOSTICS variavel = item [ , ... ];
> ```

Este comando permite a recuperação dos indicadores de status do sistema. Cada `item` é uma palavra-chave que identifica um valor de estado a ser atribuído à variável especificada (que deve ser do tipo de dados correto para recebê-la). Os itens de status atualmente disponíveis são `ROW_COUNT`, o número de linhas processadas pelo último comando SQL enviado ao mecanismo SQL e `RESULT_OID`, o `OID` da última linha inserida pelo comando SQL mais recente. Note que `RESULT_OID` só é útil após um comando `INSERT` em uma tabela contendo `OIDs`.

---

Referência: [**@@ROWCOUNT in PostgreSQL 9.3**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325731/3388148).